# WCF Keep Alive and Backup Strategy

Tags: wcf, backup

Is that possible (using behavior and IClientMessageInspector.BeforeSendRequest) to change the comunication channel before send a message ?

I need to change this, because i have a backup/primary strategy for my proxy.

Comment: Short answer is no - once a communication channel is created, it can't be modified.  `IClientMessageInspector.BeforeSendRequest` is usually used for actions that relate to the message, not the channel.  What exactly are you trying to do?  Folks might be able to suggest ways to accomplish it.

Comment: I'd like to implement a high availability strategy for my wcf channel, wich detects when the primary host is down and reconnects to another service (that will be especificed in some xml).

Let me know if is there any dll that wrapper a wcf call to achieve this.

I saw loads of topics about WCF and keep alive strategies, but i never saw an elegant solution for this ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, it sounds like you want to be able to switch service endpoints in mid-call if the primary service is offline.  I don't think there's any way to do that - at least not elegantly.

Once a communication channel is established, it's pretty much set until it is closed (or aborted).  There's no way to switch it from one endpoint to a different (backup) endpoint - you couldn't even do it by creating a new channel because the proxy would still be using the primary endpoint.

Based on my understanding of WCF, about the closest you could come would be for the client to detect that the primary service was not responding (most likely through a timeout), and then it could switch to a proxy configured for the secondary/backup service.

Now, you *might* be able to, within `IClientMessageInspector.BeforeSendRequest` do some checking to see if the service is responsive, and if it does not response try to generate a new proxy with the backup service endpoint and send the message there...**BUT** I don't know if that would work, and even if it did it strikes me as a bit of a kludge.

Simplest solution is that the client simply switches to the alternate service endpoint if the primary endpoint is down, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but for future reference.

I think WCF Routing (.NET4) is what you are looking for, namespace "System.ServiceModel.Routing.RoutingService". Search for "High Availability" on this page, [Practical Messaging Scenarios with WCF 4](http://www.code-magazine.com/articleprint.aspx?quickid=1009051&printmode=true), for an example.

From [1](http://www.code-magazine.com/articleprint.aspx?quickid=1009051&printmode=true): "The back up list indicates to the Routing Service that if the primary endpoint, OneWayService1 is not available (i.e., it fails to respond), the Routing Service should try each subsequent endpoint beginning with OneWayService2 and ending with OneWayService4 until a service responds."